# UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to create new instance of TessBaseAPI

Tags: java, android, tesseract

This is a weird error because it doesn't happen every time - mostly rare - so it's difficult to debug.
This is the line where the error occurs:

```
TessBaseAPI tessBaseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
```

I use [this library](https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android) to connect Tesseract with Android.

The error log:

> E/linker: package com.app.myapp: library "/system/lib64/libjpeg.so"
> ("/system/lib64/libjpeg.so") needed or dlopened by
> "/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the
> namespace: [name="classloader-namespace", ld_library_paths="",
> default_library_paths="/data/app/com.app.myapp-4EcKvX8ZmvEUrqVJAF20Dg==/lib/arm64:/data/app/com.app.myapp-4EcKvX8ZmvEUrqVJAF20Dg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a",
> permitted_paths="/data:/mnt/expand:/mnt/asec:/data/data/com.app.myapp"]
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main
> Process: com.app.myapp, PID: 6393
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libjpeg.so" needed or dlopened by
> "/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace
> "classloader-namespace"
> at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
> at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.(TessBaseAPI.java:52)
> at com.app.myapp.utils.UtilsOCR.getTessBaseAPI(UtilsOCR.java:257)
> at com.app.myapp.ocr.OCRTextEvaluator.init(OCRTextEvaluator.java:381)
> at com.app.myapp.ocr.OCRTextEvaluator.(OCRTextEvaluator.java:48)
> at com.app.myapp.helper.NotebookWriter.init(NotebookWriter.java:530)
> at com.app.myapp.helper.NotebookWriter.(NotebookWriter.java:89)

Inside TessBaseAPI class the error occurs in this line:

```
System.loadLibrary("jpeg");
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.